# Css prints a second div

Tags: html, css

If you look on this site http://kids.nineplanets.org/ in mobile resolution you will find that the menu is not showing because of some random css.

Here is the structure where i have the problem

```
<div class="wrap">
<div id="mobile-menu-icon"></div>

<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu genesis-nav-menu menu-primary mobile-menu">
<li class="menu-item"><a href="portfoli.htm">The Sun</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="mercury.htm">Mercury</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="venus.htm">Venus</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="earth.htm">Earth</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="mars.htm">Mars</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="asteroid.htm">Asteroid Belt</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="jupiter.htm">Jupiter</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="saturn.htm">Saturn</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="uranus.htm">Uranus</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="neptune.htm">Neptune</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="pluto.htm">Pluto</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="fotomo.htm">Photos</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

And this is the css where i'm trying to solve the problem.

```
#mobile-menu-icon {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        padding: 20px 0;
        padding: 1.25rem 0;
        text-align: center;
    }



    #mobile-menu-icon:hover::before {
        color: #4bbdbd;
        content: 'MENU \2637';
    } 

    #mobile-menu-icon:active::before {
        color: #4bbdbd;
        content: 'MENU \2637';
    } 

    .crave-citrus #mobile-menu-icon::before {
        color: #ee506b;
        content: 'MENU \2630';
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

    .crave-citrus #mobile-menu-icon:hover::before {
        color: #ee506b;
        content: 'MENU \2637';
    } 

    .crave-citrus #mobile-menu-icon:active::before {
        color: #ee506b;
        content: 'MENU \2637';
    }

    .crave-berry #mobile-menu-icon::before {
        color: #896da7;
        content: 'MENU \2630';
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    } 

    .crave-berry #mobile-menu-icon:hover::before {
        color: #896da7;
        content: 'MENU \2637';
    }

    .crave-berry #mobile-menu-icon:active::before {
        color: #896da7;
        content: 'MENU \2637';
    }
```

I have fixed the problem with the overlap with the wraper but now all i see are 2 menus.
The second one bellow it's a before selector printed by css and i want to get rid of it but when i try with the code above it always arase and the original!

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the problem..it's not css that displays the menu icon two times..there are two `<div id="mobile-menu-icon">` in your markup.

Comment: **"this site http://kids.nineplanets.org/ in mobile resolution you will find that the menu is not showing"**, Why we need to open your site in Mobile resolution. Rather than that, you could have share a screenshot of the issue. That would be helpful us to help you.

Comment: So you have one menu in the 'wrap' div, one menu in the 'crave-citrus' div and one menu in the 'crave-berry' div? And they're all the same or something?

Comment: @naele if you look the code i gave you there is only one div with that class and the site print's two

Comment: @siva charan yeap you are right i will show you with a screenshot!

Comment: @amber to tell the truth i'm confused myself its a clients website and i struggle to find what is that... that's why i gave the sites url

Comment: <div class="wrap">
    <div id="mobile-menu-icon"></div>
    <div id="mobile-menu-icon"></div>
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu genesis-nav-menu menu-primary mobile-menu">...</ul>
</div>

Comment: please stop saying the 'sites prints' or 'css prints' :P you wrote the code, right? :P

Comment: @Naele Hah no my friend this is a clients website and im hired to fix it in responsive :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `mobile-menu.js` there is below code

```
$(".menu-primary").addClass("mobile-menu").before('<div id="mobile-menu-icon"></div>');
```

you need to remove the above line. and then your problem will solve. Because of this line two menus are showing in your mobile view.

Comment: aha , the jquery was "printing" the div :) , glad its resolved

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
$(".menu-primary").addClass("mobile-menu").before('<div id="mobile-menu-icon"></div>');
```

with this code

```
$(".menu-primary").addClass("mobile-menu");
```

in `homepage_files/mobile-menu.js`. This should work.